# Is there a way to find amount of EOS delegated to other accounts from yours?

Tags: cleos, accounts

I would like to know if there is a way to find out if you can find the total EOS staked to other accounts other than your own. I have a certain amount of EOS staked but only a part of it is staked to the account I own. The other missing amount I have loss tracked to I have delegated to. Is there a cleos command for this? I would I have to go back through my account history?